# CORBA files unresolved reference in Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: c++, linker, corba

If I have a `server.idl` file which generates `server.hh` and `server.cc`. I add them both to a Visual C++ 6.0 project. And I get an link error `unresolved external symbol` for a function that is is declared in `server.hh` and defined in `server.cc`. I have never used Visual C++ 6.0 so my question is there anything else I need to do for the linker to be able to pick up `server.cc` file besides including it in `Included Source Files` folder? maybe along the lines of including a folder where the file resides to the project somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add `server.cc` to your project just like in any newer version or use `#include` to pull it into another file that is compiled (probably bad practice). Other than that, it's hard to guess without seeing the actual source. Any specific reason you're still using Visual C++ 6.0 for this?

Comment: Ended up doing exactly that before looking at the answer, thanks though. Still using 6.0 for that particular project since legacy code was written without compliance with the standard, should convert it though...